# ubuntu 14.04: How to compress a directory which have symlinks?

Tags: 14.04, backup, symbolic-link, zip, unzip

I have a php project of size 3.5GB in which there are symlinks of several files. I want to zip it and take backup to windows 10 PC from my ubuntu 14.04 laptop. Whenever, I make a zip file of it and take backup in PC and when i copy the backup zip file of my project back from windows PC to laptop and unzip it then the symlinks are not there instead the symlinks are shown as normal php files.
[image: Image with symlinks]

[image: Image without symlinks]

first image is with symlinks and seconds is without symlinks. What is the proper way to zip a large folder so that I will not loose any symlinks?

Comment: You will probably need to move a way from zip and instead use a tar achive. This supports Unix/Linux features like symbolic links and linux permission. Beware: the archive will only contain the link, not the actual content of the linked file, but that is apparently what you are looking for.

Comment: @vanadium i never tried tar archive because i will save my backup in windows PC it might be affected... but let me give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: It does not matter where you save the archive. The archive is just a data file. If you want to preserve symlinks, you of course can only restore the backup on a system that supports unix symbolic links. Anyway, see my answer: you still may store symbolic links in a ZIP file.

Comment: @vanadium can you please explain a bit about .tar and .tar.gz i have compressed with .tar it did not compress the project size was same... with .tar.gz it was compressed from 3.5 to 1.

Comment: tar in not compressed. tar.gz is compressed uzing the gzip format.

Comment: so should i use tar.gz ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83514/discussion-between-vanadium-and-haroon).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, a simple search reveals an anwer. The standard zip utility that comes with Ubuntu (Info-ZIP) comes with an option that allows to store symlinks as symlinks. By default, symlinks are dereferenced, i.e., the actual file linked to is included in the zip, as you experienced. The command might look like:

`zip --symlinks -r foo.zip foo/`

(credit goes to the [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/265675/how-can-i-zip-compress-a-symlink) site)

You may consider using compressed tar archive formats instead for this task. The tar archive format by design supports linux file system features including symbolic links, file permissions, whereas zip originally has its origins rather in the MS Windows environment.